# Laravel Unique validation on Composite key upon Update

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add a validation rule for the composite key in Laravel. The validation rule working fine for adding a new record but while updating same record it gives error as name is already taken.

```
      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
        'name' => 'required|unique:labs,name,NULL,id,service_id,'.$request>input('service_id'),
    ]);
```

Thanks in advance.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I find update on unique pain in the ass too. Do you have soft deletes on your model ?

Comment: I disagree - if you only allow full update it makes total sense.

Comment: What the OP is saying is that when he makes a unique validation, upon updating and hitting submit with no changes made, it shows up the validation error. In this case, it needs to ignore the unique field

Comment: @workservice yes i am using soft delete.

Comment: It giving the same error as the name already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need it to ignore the current ID. That can be done within the unique rule as documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$service_id = // query here for the CURRENT service_id (not the one in the request), as you want to ignore the current one

Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('service_id')->ignore($service_id),
    ]
]);
```

Ensure to ignore the current service_id from the unique, not the one in the request.

Comment: Or you can make Request class and pass there an `$id = null`. If you try to update the record with no changes made it should ignore the id and not return validation error

Comment: That depends on what you want. If you only allow full update (typically via put) you can do it like this. Based on the question that's what I assume right now